# Xamarin XAML error on Master-Detail Page when passing a parameter to a detail view constructor

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

When I want to pass a parameter to the view constructor I am getting an error in the MasterDetailPage xaml.
Error: No constructors found for Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage with matching x:Arguments.

MasterDetailPage:

```
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:LoginMasterDetailPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
         <pages:LoginView/>
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

LoginView:

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginView : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginView(bool showAutoLogOutMessage)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = ((ViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["Locator"]).Login;
        }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issues? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your argument defined in your xaml does not match the boolean argument in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Delete from xaml page

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
         <pages:LoginView/>
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Set in code behind, whatever you want by

```
Detail = new LoginView(paramshere);
```

or maybe later

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new LoginView(paramshere));
```